How to make persistent user login with HTTPOnly Cookie refreshToken and accessToken in React.js
When I reload page, I log out.
I have no idea how to make persistent login with HTTPOnly Cookies. When I reload page, cookies don't dissappear but I log out. I see Log in button.
When I log into the system with /login endpoint, I make another request to get user details with /getUser. I store this information with React Context API, I tried to run /getUser endpoint using useEffect with empty dependency array but that doesn't work the way I want. I need to make persistent user login but have no idea.
How can I solve this problem?
